# Toyota aygo clunking noise from the back when the car has slight movement?

Tags: toyota

Car recently just passed its mot with an advisory, which was “front arm ball joint has slight play” this makes loud banging noises when going over bumps, but I also notice when I get in the car and move about banging noises come from the back too I am only 9 stone so is not because weight and being in a small car